# how to select the rest of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

i got a problem

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i want is when the child is clicked addClass,and when the rest of parent is clicked removeClass,so when i try to do

```
$('#child').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass();
})
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $('#child').removeClass();
})
```

its not working i think its because the child is actually inside the parent,so when the child is clicked the parent clicked right?

so how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$('#child').click(function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass("myClass");
});
```

Comment: @paynestrike Please, Accept the answer by **clicking the 'V' mark.**

Answer (score 2):

You could use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('#child').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Several users have already suggested a good solution - here's an explanation of why it works:

When you click an HTML element (actually a DOM object...), the click event "bubbles" all the way up to the root element. For example, a click in `#child` also triggers a click in `#parent`, as you expected.

To stop this behavior, you need to call `.stopPropagation()` on the click event - that will tell the browser that you do not want the event to propagate, but keep it "local". Basically, when you've handled it here, you're done with it and don't want to see it again.

Conveniently, jQuery event handlers take the event as the first argument, so if you assign any function with the signature `function (e) { ... }`, you can stop event propagation by `e.stopPropagation();` as others have suggested. In your case, you want

```
$('#child').click(function(e){
  $(this).addClass();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $('#child').removeClass();
});
```

Comment: You might also be interested in knowing about `e.preventDefault()`, useful when anchor tags should not act as links, even though it's not necessarily applicable to this specific problem.